# BDD-style test framework for human driven testing

Tags: testing, bdd, robotframework

We wish to do a lot of testing which involves manual steps. These steps are physical actions that the one running the test must perform. Slowly over time we wish to automate as many steps as possible, but unless we achieve full robotics control over physical objects, the tests will never be fully automated. The automation will not be restricted to a single language or single machine, but will need to command different components via REST API / telnet / other things.

I know that [Robot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) has "manual steps" and can do pretty much everything I requested here. It also has the "mabot" manual test execution tool, which removes all automation. However, the "manual step" method is quite ugly and uses Python Tk. In addition, I would prefer tests written in a concrete syntax (such as a programming language) even though they would be BDD style (given/when/then).

So my question is: Are there any alternatives to robot framework?

Answer (score 2):

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) has the [ask keyword](http://technicaldebt.com/manual-cucumber-tests/) which may be a step in the right direction.

Any framework that allows easy addition of fixtures or similar should be able to do what you need.  The fixture can just check for the presence of a manual test result: maybe a user enters a value at the console, or puts a file somewhere, or chats on IRC, or emails some address..

- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)
- [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/FrontPage)
- [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org/)

I find theses sorts of tools on a related [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

We've been building an internal tool for doing just this; i.e. specify all your functional tests using BDD features/scenarios in Cucumber. Automate what you can, run the tests and upload the report to our tool called Xtreme BDD. You can then manually test any remaining features/scenarios, include details like environment, test execution notes, screenshots etc. It also has nice graphs to show you how much you have automated and trends overtime.

Just this week we made it open source:
https://github.com/orionhealth/XBDD/blob/master/docs/usage/user-guide.md

Comment: Thanks, we'll take a peek. However, we require tests where some steps are manual *during* test execution - such as pressing a button on external hardware. These checks cannot be done after the test is finished.